DMN Execution run with Java Spring boot with kie Getting Skipped Status and Decision result - null
Refer the DMN overview from here and include file functionality from here
(1). I have two DMN File first.dmn and second.dmn.
(2). The second.dmn file includes (imports) the first.dmn file to call the Common Decision Service.
(3). When running the second.dmn file using the Java DefaultKieSession, the decision result is null with a status of SKIPPED.
(4). Both files run successfully on Kie Sandbox (ClickHere), but when run with Java, they result in a SKIPPED status.
When I execute the second.dmn file, which includes the first.dmn file, and invoke the function or Decision Service from the first.dmn file, I ultimately obtain the decision result from the Decision Service in the first.dmn file.
In simpler terms, I'm reusing the function or Decision Service logic from first.dmn in the second.dmn file.
Assuming first.dmn contains a Decision Service that calculates A + B = C, I invoke this logic from the second.dmn file with a SUCCESS status using Java DMN execution.
I use below Library in My Spring boot Project.
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-compiler -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
 

Attach the Both DMN File Image


